# <a href> tag surrounding multiple elements somehow

Tags: html

Somehow the a href is also surrounding the 'update' image but the href
is clearly closed with a `</a>` tag. It is in a list `<li>` but I don't see how or
why this is happening. Has anyone ran into this before where the link tag is surrounding multiple elements?

```
<a href="cart.php?delete">

<img border="0" src="post_delete_icon.png">
</a>
<br>
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="item_qty[96]" size="4">
<input id="qtyx" type="text" value="1" name="qtyx" size="4">
<input type="hidden" value="96" name="productidx">
<input type="image" border="1" src="update.png">
```

Comment: By `href`, do you mean an `<a>` tag?

Comment: I wrote it. It is within an unordered list using a predefined class that comes with iwebkit. I have other href tags but this is the only one that seems to 'spill over' to another element.

Comment: Seems to work fine in jsFiddle. Input of type image have a default cursor of pointer (like a button), so maybe it looks like it's an extension of the link, but it's really not. It's acting like a submit button.

Comment: It's because jsfiddle is using the correct doctype to support his code. He's using an XHTML Strict doctype which expects closing tags on all of his elements. He could fix this by using an HTML Strict doctype or by using the HTML5 doctype. After he fixes the doctype he is going to need to remove the border attributes on all elements and add the alt attribute to his img elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Which doctype are you using?**

Based on your markup, you should be using the HTML5 doctype. If you are unfamiliar with this, place it at the top of your html markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and modify your code to:

```
<a href="cart.php?delete">
    <img src="post_delete_icon.png" alt="delete item">
</a>

<br>
<br>
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="item_qty[96]">
<input id="qtyx" type="text" size="4" value="1" name="qtyx">
<input type="hidden" value="96" name="productidx">
<input type="image" src="update.png" alt="update cart">
```

**Edit:**
Since you are using the strict doctype, you need to end your tags and follow the strict doctype rules. Run your code through an [XHTML/HTML markup validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) in order to make sure your code is compliant.

Because you are writing HTML markup, you want to use the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

After you do this, you will need to remove all of the `border="0"` attributes within your code. Those kinds of things are reserved for CSS when using the `strict` doctype. Along with the strict doctype, you will need to supply an `alt` value for your `<img>` tag. This is to improve usability and sort of a fault tolerance if the image doesn't load.

You can also stick with the XHTML doctype that you are using, but you will have to change your markup in order to follow those rules. Each doctype has it's own rules and changing doctypes in the middle of a project can completely change the way your page is rendered by the browser.

**Valid XHTML Strict code:**

```
<a href="cart.php?delete">
    <img src="post_delete_icon.png" alt="delete item"></img>
</a>
<br />
<br />
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="item_qty[96]"></input>
<input id="qtyx" type="text" value="1" name="qtyx" size="4"></input>
<input type="hidden" value="96" name="productidx"></input>
<input type="image" src="update.png"></input>
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> is what I'm using

Comment: That's your problem. In a strict doctype, you must close all tags. `<img href="....">` is invalid. It must be `<img href="..." />` You're browse is stuck to using the strict rules, but your code does not follow them so the browser is attempting to "fix" things and breaking them further.

Comment: use http://validator.w3.org/check to validate your HTML code... especially if you're using a strict doctype

Comment: Hmmm... I tried the </img> and removed the border and a no go. I did run it through the validator and I did have errors, nothing to lead me to believe whats happening should happen, but I'll fix them and get back to you! Thanks for all your help so far :)

Comment: End all of your input tags as well. I added "**Valid XHTML Strict code**" to the bottom of my answer.